# Android:How to save user input to local data?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've been doing a small project study without any android studio only terminal on Linux and aide on my phone, I successfully made a list of items that is stored on /res/values/strings.xml, it's involving a lot of components and adapters as I can see.
My question is, how to save user input to the list? Maybe not possible because it's a precompiled list?
That textEdit and addButton has empty script for now, it's just an illustration.
[image: my app]

Comment: If just want to store details I think you can do it with SQLite.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: I actually want to store and sort it in the future, but for now I want to learn to store it.

Comment: Based from the warning notice, it seems SQLite is not for a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a newbie, I would suggest you to use "SharedPreferences" in android. Simply store new value in the array and retrieve the array whenever you want and sort it.

You can also use Database (Room DB). But for storing this list.. it is not required.

You can check basic SharedPreferences tutorial online.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes, Shared preference is way to go actually, I haven't been doing in the code just yet, but I've been experimenting with it in Sketchware. In order to just make a sorted list I have to do ALot for sure. Creating a list, custom view, Map Variable, Map List, component:SharedPreferences, Save and Load the data of MapList in JSONstring, Sort manually using repeat MapList length inside another repeat of checking number up to 100 (Sketchware does not include sort function)...What I'm worried about that this sorting method'll get slower as the number inside the MapList increase

Comment: You can use a lightweight data base as well, like SQL lite

Comment: @Razvan Will it be harder or/and heavier(in app size) compared to SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work only with that xml file, you can do the following:

1. Get the value from input when the button is pressed by overriding the onClick() method from OnClickListener interface and implement there the logic.
2. Use **JAXB** to save collected data in your existing XML file.

Comment: I'll try to look at it, thanks for suggestions. But since it seems like a very new dictionary to me, is it from external library?(not a main android tools)

Comment: I'm a newbie, please guide me. So, I don't use android studio...what should I do first? Download the JAXB.jar? However, adding external libs would makes my apps size bigger than it should, I was planning to make it really small, I like it fast and simple. It just for a simple activity.

Comment: You just need to import some packages, it won't increase the size of your application. Check here the documentation to see how to use it and what to import:  https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/jaxb.html